# Easiest way to send XML via HTTP requests in Python?

Tags: python, xml, httprequest

Is there a preferred python module that could help me to send XML through a HTTP request and be able to parse the returning XML?

Comment: Will it be a SOAP message or just something-XML message? For SOAP integration with python see [suds](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/).

Comment: Relevant for parsing XML: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1912434/208339. I also like ElementTree.

Comment: The XML will be in the format of something simple like <status>0</status> or several nestings.

Answer (score 6):

One way would be to use [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html):

```
r = urllib2.Request("http://example.com", data="<xml>spam</xml>",
                     headers={'Content-Type': 'application/xml'})
u = urllib2.urlopen(r)
response = u.read()
```

Note that you have to set the content-type header, or the request will be sent `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

If that's too complicated for you, then you can also use the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) library.

For parsing the response [`lxml`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/2.3.4) is a great library, but [`elementtree`](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) will also do.

Comment: I strongly recommend `requests` in all cases.

Comment: I keep getting the error badstatusline caused by the status being empty. Is there any way to ignore this or get the responding XML?

Comment: that means your server probably doesn't return a valid http status.

Comment: why is that a problem? Is there any other module besides httplib for sending http requests?

Comment: yes, as i wrote you should try the `requests` library, it possibly can deal with a bad status better. but if you have control over the server, you should check if it's returning a valid status or why it isn't.

Comment: using the above code I get the exact same error since urllib2 just uses httplib. I do not have control over the server.