# How to fix httplib.BadStatusLine exception?

Tags: python, httplib

```
URL = "MY HTTP REQUEST URL"
XML = "<port>0</port>"

parameter = urllib.urlencode({'XML': XML})
response = urllib.urlopen(URL, parameter)
print response.read()


IOError: ('http protocol error', 0, 'got a bad status line', None)
```

I am trying to send XML to a server and get back XML. Is there any way to fix / ignore this exception?

I know that the status line is empty which is raising this error.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10707959/1350899

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to have a look what your server actually returns! It probably isn't a valid HTTP response. You could use something like this to send a raw http request to the server:

```
from socket import socket

host = 'localhost'
port = 80
path = "/your/url"
xmlmessage = "<port>0</port>"

s = socket()
s.connect((host, port))
s.send("POST %s HTTP/1.1\r\n" % path)
s.send("Host: %s\r\n" % host)
s.send("Content-Type: text/xml\r\n")
s.send("Content-Length: %d\r\n\r\n" % len(xmlmessage))
s.send(xmlmessage)
for line in s.makefile():
    print line,
s.close()
```

The response should look something like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<response headers>

<response body>
```