# How to send XML through HTTP Request in Python?

Tags: python, xml, httprequest

```
import urllib2
request = urllib2.Request("URL HERE", data="<port>0</port>",
                     headers={'Content-Type': 'application/xml'})
u = urllib2.urlopen(request)
response = u.read()
```

I tried this but found out the XML is never getting to the server. I need the XML to get to the server at the same time the HTTP request does so the proper response is sent back.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238925/python-urllib-urllib2-post  Basically, from that post, what does your URL look like and is it actually hitting the correct "page" ?

Comment: example.com/XmlApi?op=portStatus&port=0  <= This works fine, but I will need to send a large number of variables to other API methods with XML. I mean I could not use XML, and parse the incoming XML and build a big string like &port=1&blah=2&yeah=5......

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708828/how-to-fix-httplib-badstatusline-exception/10721643 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:
http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml#data