# Error while executing url lib in python

Tags: python, urllib

I am getting error while executing below line:

```
print urllib.urlopen('http://'+dns+'/password?passwd='+PASSWORD).read
```

Error:

```
IOError: ('http protocol error', 0, 'got a bad status line', None)
```

However, it's working fine with `webbrowser.open_new`

Comment: what's `dns`? Also you need to call like `.read()`

Comment: Why are you using urllib instead of Requests? Also that method you're using is depreciated https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#high-level-interface

Comment: try look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708828/how-to-fix-httplib-badstatusline-exception

Answer (score 0):

`.read` just references the method name.  Try calling it, by adding paranthesis:

```
.read()
```